# When I remove the "disabled" attribute from an asp:button it becomes enabled but doesn't postback?

Tags: asp.net

When I remove disabled attribute using jquery from asp:button it becomes enabled this button do partial postback even the OnClientClick event not fire and server side too reference of ClientID of button is perfect
Thanks in advance

Comment: We cannot see your button from our computers.

Comment: Could you post up the code you're using to enable/disable the button?